# Is there a way to get size of an attribute of type SET in Dynamodb without fetching the whole row?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Currently, I am trying to store a SET in Dynamodb as a row attribute. I could not find a way to fetch only the size of the SET.

I can always fetch the row and calculate the size of the set, but don't want to incur the  cost as I am only interested in size.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not have a way to return *just* the size of the attribute.  You're going to need to do that client-side.

You could use a Projection Expression to pull back *only* the SET attribute.  That wont save you any read units, since that cost is calculated on the items total size, but it could save you network traffic (if that's meaningful to you).

You could try creating a secondary index containing only the SET attribute, which would limit how much you have to pull back into the client to calculate the size.

I notice you said you are storing the SET attribute yourself.  Any reason you can't calculate the value before sending it to DDB?

Perhaps not directly related to your question, but there's a [DDB Item Size and Consumed Cost Calculator](https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/) you may find useful for planning/testing purposes.

Comment: I think I will end up having another attribute that has the total size, and I will update its value for each update(add or remove). Essentially, I was looking for a way to not calculate myself as Dynamodb already knows that it is a set, and returning size seemed a natural extension :D